# Magento - set default product sort on single category only

Tags: php, magento, sorting

I am trying to set default (uneditable) sort for a single category in Magento to SKU DESC and hide the sort option on that category only

basically I want this to only sort on SKU, DESC... regardless of what options were selected on other pages before hitting this page

So far I am able to hide the sort feature, no problem, but setting the sort is giving me some trouble

I have added in: /app/design/frontend/default/idp/template/catalog/category/view.phtml

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == {MY IP}) :
  if($_category->getId() == 4) :
    $_category->_data['default_sort_by'] = "sku_sort";
   endif;
endif;
```

This is setting the default sort order on this page fine, but I cannot find how to force it to go DESC instead of ASC.. any help would be appreciated

as a temporary fix until I figure this out, I am using the solution found [here](http://magento2x.com/magento-sort-newest-products-solution/), the first comment on the page has a specialized solution (changed `created_at` to `sku`)
The only problem with this solution is it affects all sku based sorting pages and results, not just the single page

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the toolbar object from the catalog/product/list.phtm removing available sort attributes and setting the default sort you need:

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
if ($_category && $_category->getId() == 4 && $this->getListBlock()){
   $availableOrders = $_category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
   unset($availableOrders['position']); // Delete the sort attributes you don't need

   $this->getListBlock()
    ->setAvailableOrders($availableOrders)
    ->setDefaultDirection('desc')
    ->setSortBy('sku_sort');
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: on `/app/design/frontend/default/idp/template/catalog/product/list.phhtml` this code doesn't do what is expected... when checking for `$this->getListBlock()` it always fails... so that block is not set (placed at top of page)